# Selection (or radio) list in Table view using Xcode iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I want to design an iPad interface that has a table view and I want to know how to make   a selection (or radio) list in Table view  using Xcode ? so I can select more than one cell in a time, like check box.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a similar UIView for radio list 
https://github.com/bishalg/BGRadioList

we can modify it to not be a radio list but a selection list.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that what exactly you want to do but I have some code in which I can select more than one images from table view and display them in one scroll view using [this](https://github.com/AalokParikh/ELCImagePickerController) code.

May this can help you to what you like to do.

Happy Coding :)

Enjoy the Day :) <3 <3 :)